# iPhone app in Flash Builder

Tags: iphone, webview, flash-builder

I've created an android app that uses WebView, through Eclipse, to display a website and navigate through it. However, now I've been assigned with creating the same app for the iPhone/iPad.

Is there any way to implement something as simple as a WebView for the iPhone while programming it through Flash Builder? (First time developing for Apple products...)

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With [Adobe Air 3](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html) you can publish apps for iOS. Making a `UIWebView` in objective-c (cocoa) and then load an external flash app (or site) won't work, since iOS devices don't allow flash embedded objects

Answer (score 0):

Create app with NewDigitalTimes [Free Apps Creator](http://newdigitaltimes.com) based on Adobe Air technology. This immediately gives all the functionality for push-notifications, analytics and advertising. Else you can use animation in app. Customize the showing Web site in the native iOS application with specifying the link.